# Paperclip with JRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, jruby

Recently I was adapting my rails app to run on JRuby.
One of problems that i've encountered was with Paperclip.
Paperclip uses Cocaine to run command line tools like ImageMagick and it uses Process.spawn, which results in:

```
Errno::ECHILD: No child processes - No child processes
                 waitpid at org/jruby/RubyProcess.java:512
                 waitpid at org/jruby/RubyProcess.java:497
                 waitpid at /home/cthulhu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/cocaine-0.3.0/lib/cocaine/command_line/runners/process_runner.rb:21
                    call at /home/cthulhu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/cocaine-0.3.0/lib/cocaine/command_line/runners/process_runner.rb:9
                 execute at /home/cthulhu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/cocaine-0.3.0/lib/cocaine/command_line.rb:77
                     run at /home/cthulhu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/cocaine-0.3.0/lib/cocaine/command_line.rb:55
                     run at /home/cthulhu/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7.2/gems/paperclip-3.2.0/lib/paperclip/helpers.rb:29
```

Is there any way to make Paperclip work smoothly with JRuby? I'm running my app on linux only, so i don't mind using linux native tools like ImageMagick.

Rails 3.2.8, JRuby 1.6.7.2

Answer (score 6):

This is still a problem in JRuby 1.7. There is a [caveat](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine#jruby-caveat) for JRuby noted on the [Cocaine](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine) Github page that defines this as a JRuby problem. For me, as of this writing, the only way to get it to work was to use

`Cocaine::CommandLine.runner = Cocaine::CommandLine::BackticksRunner.new`

as noted in the [Runners](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine#runners) section of the Cocaine Github page.

Comment: I have this issue but I don't understand where or how I should use this. Any insight?

Comment: I put the line in my answer in the file 'project/config/environments/test.rb'

Answer (score 2):

After some digging in Paperclip and Cocaine code I wrote an initializer which monkey-patches Cocaine to use [BackticksRunner](https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine/blob/master/lib/cocaine/command_line/runners/backticks_runner.rb) when on JRuby

```
if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
  module Cocaine
    class CommandLine
      def best_runner
        BackticksRunner.new
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However I'm stil looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I just pushed to master of Cocaine an accessor that will allow you to manually override the Runner.

```
Cocaine::CommandLine.runner = Cocaine::CommandLine::BackticksRunner.new
```

I don't know why jruby is reporting that Process.spawn is available when it's not, but at least we have a workaround.

Comment: small error in above code, it should be:
Cocaine::CommandLine.runner = Cocaine::CommandLine::BackticksRunner.new